# reactive object not updating on event emitted from watch

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

i'm building a complex form using this reactive obj

```js
    const formData = reactive({})
    provide('formData', formData)
```

inside the form one of the components is rendered like this:

```js
      <ComboZone
          v-model:municipality_p="formData.registry.municipality"
          v-model:province_p="formData.registry.province"
          v-model:region_p="formData.registry.region"
        />
```

this is the ComboZone render function:

```js
     setup(props: any, { emit }) {
        const { t } = useI18n()
    
        const { getters } = useStore()
        const municipalities = getters['registry/municipalities']
        const _provinces = getters['registry/provinces']
        const _regions = getters['registry/regions']
    
        const municipality = useModelWrapper(props, emit, 'municipality_p')
        const province = useModelWrapper(props, emit, 'province_p')
        const region = useModelWrapper(props, emit, 'region_p')
    
        const updateConnectedField = (key: string, collection: ComputedRef<any>) => {
          if (collection.value && collection.value.length === 1) {
            console.log(`update:${key} => ${collection.value[0].id}`)
            emit(`update:${key}`, collection.value[0].id)
          } else {
            console.log(`update:${key} =>undefined`)
            emit(`update:${key}`, undefined)
          }
        }
    
        const provinces = computed(() => (municipality.value ? _provinces[municipality.value] : []))
        const regions = computed(() => (province.value ? _regions[province.value] : []))
    
        watch(municipality, () => updateConnectedField('province_p', provinces))
        watch(province, () => updateConnectedField('region_p', regions))
    
        return { t, municipality, province, region, municipalities, provinces, regions }
      }
```

useModelWrapper :

```js
import { computed, WritableComputedRef } from 'vue'
export default function useModelWrapper(props: any, emit: any, name = 'modelValue'): WritableComputedRef<any> {
  return computed({
    get: () => props[name],
    set: (value) => {
      console.log(`useModelWrapper update:${name} => ${value}`)
      emit(`update:${name}`, value)
    }
  })
}
```

problem is that the events emitted from useModelWrapper update the formData in the parent template correctly, the events emitted from inside the watch function are delayed by one render....

Comment: you should put a minimal reproducible example of the problem in http://www.codesanbox.io like utility. I cant reproduce your issue i.e its working on my machine 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution, watchEffect wasn't the way.
Looks like was an issue with multiple events of update in the same tick, worked for me handling the  flush of the watch with  `{ flush: 'post' }` as option of the watch function.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR;

Use `watchEffect` instead of `watch`

---

...with the caveat that I haven't tried to reproduce, my guess is that you're running into this issue because you're using `watch` which runs *lazily*.
The *lazy* nature is a result of deferring execution, which is likely why you're seeing it trigger on the next cycle.

> #### [`watchEffect`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watcheffect)
>
> *Runs a function immediately while reactively tracking its dependencies and re-runs it whenever the dependencies are changed.*

> #### [`watch`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watch)
>
> *Compared to watchEffect, watch allows us to:*
>
> - *Perform the side effect lazily;*
> - *Be more specific about what state should trigger the watcher to re-run;*
> - *Access both the previous and current value of the watched state.*

Comment: mildly related, the author of `solidjs` framework has a tweet regarding update behaviour of various frameworks that is interesting here: https://twitter.com/RyanCarniato/status/1353801009844240389

Comment: hi Daniel, watchEffect does not work as well, i think i found the solution using  { flush: 'post' } in the watch function cause there are multiple updates in the same tick and also as you sayd watch is lazy

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the key: prop in components. I think it will solve the issue.